# published bot keeps getting authentication error

Tags: botframework

I have a bot that's published online on facebook , each 2 days the bot stops working , when I open the bot framework I see this error

[image]

I click on edit messenger link and resubmit and then it works fine again . I am not sure what this error means and why it's happening

Comment: Does your code run on Azure?

Comment: No , its hosted on a regular hosting site.

Answer (score 0):

A task was canceled typically means the bot did not respond within the time expected.  Too many errors, and then Facebook disables the bot and you have to resubmit.

Does your bot take a significant amount of time to respond to the request?  Alternately, are there any paths where the incoming request is not responded to with a success code (letting bot framework know the message was received)?

Comment: In the regular time no , The bot is just a translator bot so It's using google translate  . When I send the request it doesnt take more than 2 seconds . and there are not a lot of errors as the bot is not published yet , even on bot framework the errors are zero